# how to pass the text of my speech recognition to my <ion-searchbar> in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, speech-recognition, searchbar

I hope you can help me with this, you will see on the one hand I have my speech recognition that works well, and what I speak shows me well and keeps it well, the problem is that I don't know how I can pass the value obtained to me  due to later search.
It is possible to say that the  is occupying it with its property of (ionChange) = event ($ event).

This searchbar filters a list of items where I pass them through a pipe.

Comment: Can you also post some code as to what you are doing to achieve it?

Comment: html:
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]='searchBoxValue' (ionChange)='buscar($event)' debounce=500></ion-searchbar>

Comment: <ion-item *ngFor="let dest of Destino" (click)='medClicked(dest, dest.NombreCompleto)'>
            <ion-label>{{dest.NombreCompleto}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

Comment: Typescript:
Destino = [{ Abre: 'ACHA', NombreCompleto: 'ACHAO'}, {Abre: 'ALGA', NombreCompleto: 'ALGARROBO' }];

Comment: medClicked(dest1, dest ) {
    this.searchBoxValue = dest;
    }
it work, but dont filter nothing in the "Destino" in the ngfor.

Comment: Can you also write your buscar($event) {} function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432540/speech-recognition-does-not-return-good-the-value-on-time-ionic-5

there are the code, help please

Comment: // buscar(event?, buscar: string = '') {

//   if (buscar.length > 0) {
//     this.textoBuscar = buscar;
//   }
//   if (event !== undefined) {
//     this.textoBuscar = event.detail.value;

//   }
//  }

Comment: replied to your other post